# Could profiler be missing time spent on blocked call?

Tags: .net, performance, profiling

I'm profiling an app using the Visual Studio 2013 profiler, using sampling mode.  Sometimes the app makes a blocking call to a remote process using .net remoting.  Sometimes this call waits a long time for the response.  For example, in a 30 second interval it may spend 10 seconds waiting for the response.  I'd expect it to show up as a hot spot, because the call to the remote process would be present on the stack for many samples.  But, it doesn't.  Time spent in the calling method comes up as negligible.  Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sampling mode, that profiler does not sample when the thread is blocked.
Therefore it is blind to I/O, even if it takes 99.9% of the time.
(They call it "CPU Sampling", trying to make it sound like a feature.)

In instrumenting mode it works by timers rather than samples, so it includes blocked time, but it only gives function-level resolution.

The second answer to [*this question*](http://archive.today/9r927) lays out all of these issues.

Answer (score 2):

Hotspots are related to CPU utilization, a blocked thread would not qualify in this instance so what you are seeing is correct.